# grep() function

Tags: r, regex, web-scraping

I've done some web-scraping and have a character string, my_html, with links that I would like

I want to `grep()` and tried (an example of my_html which is much longer)

```
my_html <- 'stuff more stuff ...
<TD ><A CLASS=my_link HREF=\"https://www.stuff.com/secure-bin/my_club/myrep.cgi/tpw9109.cry?scrtpw9109.cry\">
other stuff
<p> www.google.com </p>
end'



my_pattern <- "<TD><A CLASS=my_link HREF=*>"
grep(my_pattern,x=my_html,value=TRUE)
```

which gets me

```
character(0)
```

I think the problem is to do with the special characters in the pattern, but I don't know the remedy.

Comment: Does `fixed=TRUE` as a parameter to `grep` help?

Comment: '*' doesn't mean 'anything' in R regex, it means 'zero or more of the preceding character'.  `<td>` also won't match `<td >`

Comment: Just added an example string

Comment: It's not matching in part because there is a space following `TD` in `my_html` (`<TD >`), but not in your regex (`<TD>`).

Comment: @Josh: Thanks, I corrected the typo. Still didn't work. Dwin's solution worked though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> sub( '(^.+HREF=\\\")(.+)(\".+)', "\\2", my_html)
[1] "https://www.stuff.com/secure-bin/my_club/myrep.cgi/tpw9109.cry?scrtpw9109.cry"
```

Basically throws away anything before the `HREF=\"` using 2 backslashes to represent a single backslash and `\"` to represent a double quote. Then includes anything before the next double quote as the second matched section and anything from that mark to the end as the third section. So it should return only the middle matching section (if one exists).